# Echoing success after uploaded

Tags: php, html

I want to echo "success" on the same page the form is on if it uploaded correctly, but Im new to php so dont know how its done?

index.php

```
<form action="upload" method="POST">
<input name="field1" placeholder="First name" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

upload.php

```
    $content = "".$_POST["field1"];
$fp = fopen("upload/test.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

I also need it to redirect back to same page index.php

Comment: This isn't a PHP problem, but a JavaScript problem.  You need to use AJAX.  Alternatively, redirect back to the page you were on (using the `Location:` header) and pass a message in the querystring `?message=success` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to echo on the same page and you don't want to use ajax there are 2 possible solution.

a) Use a GET parameter on upload script, and thread this on the index.php (As @Brad also said at comment)

upload.php

```
$content = "".$_POST["field1"];
$fp = fopen("upload/test.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
header('Location: /index.php?m=success');
```

index.php

```
//Check for message parameter
if (isset($_GET['m']{0}) && $_GET['m'] === 'success')
    echo 'Form uploaded successfully';

//Display the upload form
echo '<form action="upload" method="POST">' .
     '<input name="field1" placeholder="First name" type="text" />' .
     '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">';
```

b) Within the same script
index.php

```
//Check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['field1']))
{
    $content = "".$_POST["field1"];
    $fp = fopen("upload/test.txt","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp);

    //Do anything else
}

//Display form. Use index.php as the action, instead of upload
echo '<form action="/index.php" method="POST">' .
     '<input name="field1" placeholder="First name" type="text" />' .
     '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">';
```

**Update after comment**:

When you open a file with the fopen function, you define 2 arguments. The first argument is the filename, and the second argument is the flags.

You need the 'a' (append) flag, instead of 'w' (write):

- 'a' Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the
  file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
- 'w' Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning
  of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does
  not exist, attempt to create it.

Take a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: Thanks man!! works perfectly! However the text overwrites the current text in file, how can I do it so it writes it to the bottom of the text file?

Comment: Thanks man, used a+ instead of w, your amazing :)

Comment: Thanks man ur amazing, used a+ instead of w and it works!
sorry to be a pain but 1 more question, how would I do it so it enters the text on a different line each time and not the same line?

Comment: Add a newline character to the string that you are appending. Eg: $content = "".$_POST["field1"] . "\n";

Comment: Thanks, \n didnt work so used \r\n and it works fine now.
Thanks for the help everyone!!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this when using a regular form post. When a form is posted the user navigates away from the current page and is given a new page by the server. The one they were looking at no longer exists, so you cannot inject a message.

If you want to perform the task as you describe you will need to use an AJAX-based file uploader.

See:https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+jquery+ajax+upload

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "".$_POST["field1"];
$fp = fopen("upload/test.txt","wb");
if (fwrite($fp,$content))
  {
  echo "Successful upload!";
  } else {
  echo "Not successful!";
  };
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: The OP said it needs to be echoed "on the same page" as the form.

Comment: Oh thanks, with a GET variable on reload?

Comment: I'm assuming more along the lines of AJAX.

Comment: He said he was new to PHP, AJAX is probably on another level.  Just trying for simplicity here.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some javascript along with php to get what you are looking for.
[ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery)

I haven't tried it, but at first glance looks like a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the following code
if (! move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ['attachment'] ['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR  )) {
    //handle if file not  uploaded

         header("Location:index.php?m=fail");
}else{

      header("Location:index.php?m=success");

}
```

Comment: Session is not the preferred way to do this. If you have multiple hits to the same php script at the same moment (race condition), it is possible that the one connection sets the value to the session, and another connection reads and resets the flag. You cannot guarantee that the first connection will be be the connection that will read the value from the session.

Comment: I agree... using session needs some careful clearing of session variables at the right point.  using get params to return success or failure is a good way to handle it.